# How to pass array value as object key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

[image]

I am having some issue when i try to pass data in my react app.
How I am suppose to pass filtered[0][0] as key to data object?

Comment: please no images. just add all relevant parts in text from to the question.

Comment: If `filtered` is an array, `data["someKey"][filtered[0][0]]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data["someKey"][filtered[0][0]] should work

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with nested objects , there can be two cases

1. Where we know the Key : In such case we can use `a.something.otherKey`
2. Where we fetch key dynamically: In that case we use `a[something][otherKey]`

I will demonstrate it by following example, Let's have two objects.
`person={
      "name":"Ram",
      "age":27,
      "vehicles": {
         "car":"limousine",
         "bike":"ktm-duke",
         "airlines":{
            "lufthansa" : "Air123",
             "British airways" : "Brt707"
         }
      }
   }`
and 
`airlines=["lufthansa","British airways"]`

Now lets fetch value of "lufthansa" in person object.
We do it as `a["vehicles"]["airlines"][b[0]]`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @acbay here is the answer:
If filtered is an array, data["someKey"][filtered[0][0]] should work. – acbay

Comment: Let me do it for you, so you can mark it as answer:)